# How to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin using reactjs and webpack?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, webpack, cors, axios

I'm runing reactjs in a localhosted server using webpack. I need to make an ajax call from my reactjs application (client side) to my backend, which is also a local hosted server but using a different port. When i make a request to my backend from postman, there is no problem. But when i try to do the same from my react js application, i got this error in my console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:15)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

It's seems to be a C.O.R.S issue. After several hours of research on internet i can't find a solution.

There is my code

react :

```html
handleClick(){
      console.log('focused')
      axios.get('http://localhost:8888/api').then(function(result){
        console.log(result)
      })
    }
```

webpack config

```html
devServer: {
     contentBase: 'http://localhost',
     port: 8888,
     // Send API requests on localhost to API server get around CORS.
     proxy: {
        '/api': {
           target: {
              host: "localhost",
              protocol: 'http:',
              port: 3000
           }
        }
     }


  }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: This seems very much like a serverside error. Would you mind sharing the code of the /api route?

Comment: did you try adding cors headers to the devServer config? https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/533

Comment: @DavinTryon i've added cors headers in the devServer object just like explained in the example but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try making your call without the host like this:

```
handleClick(){
     console.log('focused')
     axios.get('/api').then(function(result){
        console.log(result)
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It doesn't work. I get an error `404 (Not Found)`